# R: If my vector grouped by ID contains a certain value, return one value, else return other value

Tags: r, tidyverse

Each ID variable has multiple rows, and I'd like to create a vector that tells me if any of the runs (rows within that id) contains "orange."

Otherwise, I'd like it to return "apple" if "orange" is not contained on any of the rows for that id.

I'm guessing it's something like

```
data_desired <- data %>%
group_by("ID") %>%
mutate(AnyOrange = ...)
```

but that's where I'm stuck...sample data and desired outcome below:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Run, ~Oranges,
  #--/---/---
  "a", 1, "orange",
  "a", 2,  "orange",
  "b", 1, "apple",
  "b", 2, "apple",
  "b", 3, "orange",
  "c", 1, "apple",
  "c", 2, "apple"
)

# Desired Outcome
data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Run, ~Oranges, ~AnyOrange,
  #--/---/---/---
  "a", 1, "orange","orange",
  "a", 2,  "orange","orange",
  "b", 1, "apple","orange",
  "b", 2, "apple","orange",
  "b", 3, "orange","orange",
  "c", 1, "apple","apple",
  "c", 2, "apple","apple"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(AnyOrange = ifelse(any(Oranges=='orange'), 'orange', Oranges))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID      Run Oranges AnyOrange
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    
1 a         1 orange  orange   
2 a         2 orange  orange   
3 b         1 apple   orange   
4 b         2 apple   orange   
5 b         3 orange  orange   
6 c         1 apple   apple    
7 c         2 apple   apple
```

Answer (score 2):

The column names should be unquoted within the tidyverse functions.  Otherwise, after grouping by 'ID', `match` for 'orange' to get the index of first 'orange' value, use it to subset the 'Oranges' and then `coalesce` with the original 'Oranges' column

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(AnyOrange = coalesce(Oranges[match('orange', Oranges)], Oranges)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  ID      Run Oranges AnyOrange
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    
1 a         1 orange  orange   
2 a         2 orange  orange   
3 b         1 apple   orange   
4 b         2 apple   orange   
5 b         3 orange  orange   
6 c         1 apple   apple    
7 c         2 apple   apple
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `dplyr` approach:
Basically it is similar to @onyambu's  solution. Here we use `%in%` operator:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(AnyOrange = ifelse("orange" %in% Oranges, "orange","apple"))
```

```
ID      Run Oranges AnyOrange
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    
1 a         1 orange  orange   
2 a         2 orange  orange   
3 b         1 apple   orange   
4 b         2 apple   orange   
5 b         3 orange  orange   
6 c         1 apple   apple    
7 c         2 apple   apple
```